# Bazel execute python script before running cc_binary

Tags: python, c++, bazel, build-system, starlark

I am trying to create a bazel target which will run c++ binary from .cpp file, which is dynamically generated by python script.

Lets say I have generator.py which creates in the dir a generated.cpp file.

My rules looks like this:

```
# py_binary(
#     name = "generator",
#     srcs = [
#         "src/generator.py"
#     ],
#     main = "src/generator.py",
#     data = [
#         ":generator_inputs",
#     ],
#     imports = ["."],
# )
   
# cc_binary(
#     name = "run_generated_cpp",
#     srcs = ["src/generated.cpp"],
#     deps = [
#         "//cpp_lib",
#     ]
# )
```

How Can I combine this 2 targets into 1 ? So that executing cc_binary has a preprocess step of generating file from py script.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use a [genrule](https://bazel.build/reference/be/general#genrule). Genrules enable you to execute a binary during the build and they can produce outputs which other rules can declare as inputs. I didn't actually test the code below, but the general idea is you define your generator binary and specify that target in the `tools` list of a genrule target, use the `$(location)` helper to invoke the tool in the `cmd` field of the genrule, and declare the generated files as outputs of the genrule. Once declared, these can be used as inputs to other rules.

```
py_binary(
    name = "generator",
    srcs = [
        "src/generator.py"
    ],
    main = "src/generator.py",
    data = [
        ":generator_inputs",
    ],
    imports = ["."],
)

genrule(
    name = "generated_cpp_sources",
    outs = ["src/generated.cpp"],
    tools = [":generator"],
    cmd = "$(location :generator)"
)
   
cc_binary(
    name = "run_generated_cpp",
    srcs = ["src/generated.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "//cpp_lib",
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thats exactly the solution I was looking for. Thanks !

Comment: Figuring out where to write `src/generated.cpp` from the Python script is tricky. I usually add `$(location src/generated.cpp)` to the command line so the script can get the location from there.